# Controls.Add With Comments?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
var ph = Page.FindControl("phHead");

if (null != ph)
{
   var metaTag = new HtmlGenericControl("meta");

   metaTag.Attributes.Add("name", "name_goes_here");
   metaTag.Attributes.Add("content", "content_goes_here");

   ph.Controls.Add(metaTag);
}
```

What I need to do is a comment into the same control. Is there a way to create a control that's just plain old `<!-- comment here -->` and use it in `Controls.Add()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`LiteralControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) and populate it with an HTML comment.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. I'll accept it when I can (have to wait X minutes).

Answer (score 4):

```
  this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<!-- My comments-->"));
```

Something like that?